# This ranks fairly high on my list

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech, linking-verbs

Is *rank* a copulative/linking verb in T*his **ranks** fairly high on my list* ?

What Part of Speech is *high* here?

**High** (adjective) https://www.oed.com/oed2/00106032

**High** (adverb) https://www.oed.com/oed2/00106033

**Rank** (verb)  https://www.oed.com/oed2/00197225

Comment: Looks like the average verb, and *high* is an average adjective, like 'important'.

Comment: _She is currently the **highest** ranked player in the world. Health and education rank **highly** with voters_ https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rank_2

Comment: I'd say that "rank" can take a predicative complement, and hence "high on my list" is an AdjP functioning as subjective PC. Compare "This **is** fairly high on my list".

Comment: @BillJ what bout _Health and education **rank highly** with voters_ ?oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rank_2

Comment: "Rank highly" is just a VP headed by "rank", which is modified by the adverb "highly".

Comment: @BillJ thanks, but does _rank_ mean the same in both?

Comment: @Yosef Baskin The average verb occurs followed by just an adjective phrase?

Comment: Compare ['Will this question be rated relatively high?' or ' ... relatively highly?'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334198/will-this-question-be-rated-relatively-high-or-relatively-highly).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, this looks green. That tasted yummy.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin The average verb is either intransitive or takes a DO (some do both). Linking verbs are far rarer.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED), we find the following in the entry for the **adverb** *high* :

> In a high position; at a high altitude; far up, aloft.
> **Often overlapping with or difficult to distinguish from the adjective used as the complement of a verb.**

The sentence

[1] *This ranks fairly high on my list.*

would seem to be one of those cases where one could fairly interpret *high* as either an adjective or an adverb.

If, in your sentence, *high* is interpreted as an adjective, then indeed you could say that *rank* functions as a 'linking/copulative' verb—**if** by that you mean that it takes a PC as complement (as BillJ said in the comments).

On the other hand, if, in your sentence, *high* is interpreted as an adverb, then *rank* would not be a 'linking/copulative' verb—**if** by that you mean that its complement is **not** a PC.

**Discussion**

With some other verbs, there is no ambiguity. For example, *high* is definitely an adverb in

[2] *He climbed **high** on the list of the state's most sought-after criminals.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Alias_Frank_Canton/-OVbppVUWDAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22climbed%20high%20on%20the%20list%22&pg=PA39&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22climbed%20high%20on%20the%20list%22)

because *climb* cannot take an adjective phrase as a complement. For example, it's *he climbed **beautifully,*** not <sup>*</sup>*he climbed **beautiful***.

And it is definitely an adjective in

[3] *Courtesy never seemed **high** on the list.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Accidental_Viscountess/oFHGDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22seemed%20high%20on%20the%20list%22&pg=PT6&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22never%20seemed%20high%20on%20the%22)

since *seem* takes a predictive complement (PC) as a complement, and a PC must be a noun phrase (NP) or and adjective phrase (AdjP). And so it's *he seemed **beautiful,*** not <sup>*</sup>*he seemed **beautifully***.

But *rank* can take either an adjective phrase (AdjP) or an adverb phrase (AdvP) complement:

[4]  i  *There are many ways not to be a sportsman, and
           neglecting limb lines and trot lines **ranks highly***      [AdvP as complement; [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Outdoor_Oklahoma/bgVNAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22ranks+highly+on+the+list%22&dq=%22ranks+highly+on+the+list%22&printsec=frontcover)]
          ***on the list,***

ii  *We in the Air Force consider that it **ranks equal

           in priority.***                                                                        [AdjP as complement; [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Military_Construction_Authorization_Fisc/ZXiCY3MmA-YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22it%20ranks%20equal%20in%20priority%22&pg=PA350&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22it%20ranks%20equal%20in%20priority%22)]

And since *high* can be either an adjective or an adverb, it is ambiguous what kind of complement it is in [1].

Comment: "At or to a large value, amount or price"
_Students who scored **high** on the test went on to do very well._ BUT "At or to a high standard, level or amount" 
_**highly** trained/educated, 
a **highly** paid job_ https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/high_2

Comment: Those are the only meanings which both **high(ly)** apparently have in common.

Comment: **High** (adverb) https://www.oed.com/oed2/00106033 vs (adjective) https://www.oed.com/oed2/00106032. **Rank** (verb) https://www.oed.com/oed2/00197225

Comment: @GJC Thanks! Note, however, that the only purpose of using *highly* in [4i] was to demonstrate that *rank* does take AdvPs as complements. In principle, I could have used any other AdvP whose head is as clearly an adverb as *highly* is. But it so happens that among complements of *rank* whose heads are completely unambiguously adverbs, those headed by *highly* seem to be the easiest to find examples of (in the published literature). Anyway, to repeat: for my purposes, it does not matter whether *highly* in [4i] has the same meaning as *high* does (in its adverb interpretation) in [1].